# How do I increment results using innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have my code setup, I just cant get the results number to increment everytime the processUserText button is clicked, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function userHTML() {
    var uput = document.getElementById('uput').value;
    var num=1; 
    num = num ++;
    var html = num +  '.' + uput + '<br>' ;  
    //document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += html;
} 
document.getElementById("processUserText").onclick = function() {

}
document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function(){  
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
}
document.getElementById('processUserText').addEventListener("click", userHTML);
```

The HTML:

```
<input name="uput" id="uput" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter your input!"/>
<input type="button" value="processUserText" id="processUserText">
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset">
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: what is `var uput = document.getElementById('uput')`

Comment: Try `num++;` instead of `num = num ++;`

Comment: Every time you call `userHTML`, you are (re)setting `num` to `1`. You could easily figure this out yourself if you set a breakpoint and step through your code. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en) if you don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. hope it helps...

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Index Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input name="uput" id="uput" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter your input!"/>
            <input type="button" value="processUserText" id="processUserText">
            <input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset">
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i = 0;
            function userHTML() {
                var uput = document.getElementById('uput').value;
                var num = i;
                var html = num +  '. ' + uput + '<br>' ;  
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += html;
            } 
            document.getElementById("processUserText").onclick = function() {
                i++;
                userHTML();
            }
            document.getElementById("reset").onclick = function() {
                i = 0;
                document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is not that useful. Please explain your solution, do not just post code.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare the `num` variable outside of the function. If it is declared inside of the function, its value is not preserved between calls of the function.

Instead of

```
function userHTML() {
    var num = 1;
    num++;
    // get user input and show new value
}
```

Do something like this

```
var num = 1;
function userHTML() {
    // get user input and show new value
    num++;
}
```

Additionally, the line `num = num++;` does not actually increment `num`. All you need to do is `num++`. The reason for this is a subtle difference between `num++`, called postincrement, and `++num`, preincrement. This code illustrates the difference:

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a++); // 1
console.log(a); // 2

var b = 1;
console.log(++b); // 2
console.log(b); // 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `var num=1;` outside of the `userHTML()` function (otherwise it's always going to be set to 1 each time it's called).

And change `num = num ++;` to `num++;` as the first one just assigns num = num due to the precedence of the ++ operator.

Answer (score 0):

You declear `num` inside of function. So, what's happen for this ? `Num` is increasing but as it's declare inside of function it sets again into 1. So, you need to write it outside of the function :

```
var num=1;
function userHTML(){
}
```

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5sp846x7/